# How to run execute a command in project directory in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have the following task

```
task runSomeTool(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: 'jar') {
....
    "git config remote.origin.url".execute().text.trim()
....
}
```

which returns and empty string.
When I change the command string to list all properties (`git config --list`), I see that it is listing the global config properties. This led me to discover that it runs in `${user.dir}/.gradle/daemon/6.8.3/` directory. 
Is there anyway I can execute the command in `$projectDir`?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [ProcessBuilder](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-processbuilder-api) instead

```
public String gitProperty(String command, String... argsArray){
    def commandArgs = ["git", command]
    if (argsArray.length > 0)
        commandArgs+=argsArray.flatten()ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandArgs)
    // To make sure it executes in the correct directory
    pb.directory(new File ("${wDir}"))
    Process p = pb.start()
    //Wait for the process to finish
    p.waitFor()
    String result = new String(p.getInputStream().readAllBytes())
    return result.trim()
}
```

**wDir**, in this case, is the working directory one specifies.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the `workingDir` param, described here for a couple tasks:

- JavaExec: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html
- Exec: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

```
task runSomeTool(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "${rootProject.projectDir}"
    commandLine 'git'
    args "status"
}
```

Comment: I actually ended up using ProcessBuilder which worked just fine.